# Override parent class attribute before super() call in Python 3

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance, attributes

Consider the following example. The `Parent` class has an attribute called `attr`. Both `Child1` and `Child2` have an attribute with the same name. The only difference between `Child1` and `Child2` is that `Child1` calls `super()` before overriding the parent's `attr` attribute. `Child2` instead does not seem to override the parent's `attr` because the attribute is defined before the `super()` call. Is there a way for `Child2` to override the parent's `attr` while defining it before a `super()` call?

```
class Parent():

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = "parent"

class Child1(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attr = "child1"

class Child2(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = "child2"
        super().__init__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child1 = Child1()
    print(child1.attr) # "child1"

    child2 = Child2()
    print(child2.attr) # "parent"
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as *"parent's `attr`"* and *"child's `attr`"*. There is only one `attr` on that instance, regardless of whether it was set from the code in the parent class, or from the code in the child class, or from the code without the class.

In other words, these examples produce the same results:

### Example 1

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 1

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
```

### Example 2

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = 1

b = B()
```

### Example 3

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

b = B()
b.attr = 1
```

## The actual answer ;)

So, the difference between `Child1` and `Child2` is that `Child1`'s `__init__` executes this:

```
    self.attr = "parent"
    self.attr = "child1"
```

And `Child2`'s `__init__` effectively does this:

```
    self.attr = "child2"
    self.attr = "parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `super().__init__()` is shorthand for calling the super class's `__init__`, passing it the current instance as `self`.

Consider what happens when you create an instance of `Child2`. First, a "bare" instance of the class is created. This instance must be initialized. To do this, Python passes this instance to `Child2.__init__` as `self`. Now `Child2.__init__` first adds an `attr` attribute to this instance. But it next calls `super().__init__()` which, in this case, is shorthand for `Parent.__init__(self)`. Crucially, `self` is the instance of the `Child2` instance that we are initializing. So `Parent.__init__` then overwrites the `attr` attribute of this instance.

In general, it is probably best to put the `super().__init__()` invocation first in your subclass's `__init__`. This isn't really a limitation, and most people will expect it to come first.

An example to demonstrate the flow of the program:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Here I am, in the parent! My ID is: ' + str(id(self)))

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        print('Initializing new Child instance with ID: ' + str(id(self)))
        super().__init__()
```

Such that creating a instance of `Child` prints out:

```
Initializing new Child instance with ID: 4372063120
Here I am, in the parent! My ID is: 4372063120
```