# override multiple attributes inherited from parent class in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'd like to assign different values to inherited attributes in the instances of a child class. The code I use is

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, n=50):
        # there are multiple parent attributes like 'n'
        # I use just one to reproduce the error
        self.n = n
        
    def print_n(self):
        print('n =', self.n)
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a=5):
        self.a = a
        
    def print_a(self):
        print('a =', self.a)
      
son1 = Child(n=100)
son1.print_n()
```

The error message is

```
son1 = Child(n=100)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'
```

What would be the correct way to achieve the objective?

I tried to put **super().**init**()** in the ****init**** method of the child class according to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195257/override-parent-class-attribute-before-super-call-in-python-3) similar question, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your `Child` class constructor has to call the `Parent` class constructor. `super(Child, self).__init__()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Child.__init__` needs to call `Parent.__init__` explicitly; it won't happen automagically.  If you don't want `Child.__init__` to have to "know" what `Parent.__init__`'s args are, use `*args` or in this case `**kwargs` to pass through any kwargs that aren't handled by `Child.__init__`.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, n=50):
        # there are multiple parent attributes like 'n'
        # I use just one to reproduce the error
        self.n = n
        
    def print_n(self):
        print('n =', self.n)
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a=5, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a = a
        
    def print_a(self):
        print('a =', self.a)
      
son1 = Child(n=100)
son1.print_n()
```

Comment: '**kwargs' in the 'init' method is exactly what it takes! Thanks!